# Nvidia driver causing BSOD

Tags: drivers, graphics-card, bsod, nvidia-graphics-card

I get BSOD stating 'System thread not handled exception' caused by nvlddmkm.sys. This occurs whenever I am trying to boot up Windows. After Windows loading screen appears, it directly goes to BSOD stating the above error. It may reboot fine after collecting the error information but the BSOD is quite annoying.

I have checked with the device manager, it says that the device is working fine. I am using :

- Windows 10 with latest updates(OS Build 19041.264. Windows 10 Home Single Language),
- Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-4210U CPU 2.40GHz,
- NVIDIA GeForce 820M,
- 8 GB Ram,
- SSD

The version of my driver is 23.21.13.8912. I have tried uninstalling my driver and restarting the PC with no luck. I also tried installing the driver previous version and still no luck. Any idea about what is going on

Comment: where can I find the compatible one

Comment: Yes. I have installed it through windows update

Comment: Can you suggest any solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The version of my driver is 23.21.13.8912. I have tried uninstalling my driver and restarting the PC with no luck. I also tried installing the driver previous version and still no luck. Any idea about what is going on

**There is a known issue with older Nvidia drivers with `Windows 10 version 2004`.**  You should have never installed Windows 10 version 2004 while the hardware block was active.  **Based on the fact you are receiving BSODs, and the known issue specifically describes BSODs, I have a suspicion you are experiencing the known issue.**

> Nvidia and Microsoft have found incompatibility issues with certain versions of Nvidia display adapter drivers and Windows 10, version 2004 (the Windows 10 May 2020 Update). Windows 10 devices with affected Nvidia display driver versions might receive a stop error with a blue screen or other issues during or after installing the update to Windows 10, version 2004. The affected drivers are any version lower than 358.00.
>
> To safeguard your update experience, we have applied a compatibility hold on Windows 10 devices with affected Nvidia display drivers installed from being offered Windows 10, version 2004, or Windows Server, version 2004 until the driver has been updated.

The immediate solution to this problem is to rollback the installation of Windows 10 version 2004. `23.21.13.8912` was released in 2018.

If you are not already running [425.31 - WHQL](https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/drivers/results/145874/) you should upgrade immediately.  `23.21.13.8912` was released in April 2018, while the Nvidia 425.31 WHQL drivers were released in April 2019.  I am unable to determine if `23.21.13.8912`corelates to 358 or lower, based on my research though, 358.50 was released in 2015.

I believe the real problem is the known issues is effecting more than the driver version identified by Microsoft.  **At this time Microsoft has not provided an estimate for when the issue will be resolved.**

There is no other resolution to this problem other than to revert back to the previous version of Windows 10.  **If you have taken action to free up disk space, and that is not possible, you will have to wait for the issue to be resolved.**

Source: [Issue with older drivers for Nvidia display adapters (GPU)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/release-information/status-windows-10-2004#418msgdesc)

Microsoft's recommendation is not to install 2004 if you are affected by this issue.

> We recommend that you do not attempt to manually update using the Update now button or the Media Creation Tool until this issue has been resolved.

Comment: I was experiencing this issue even before updating my windows to the current version. Anyway, I was not running 425.31 - WHQL. I will upgrade it to 425.31 - WHQL. Thanks for the info. I guess I have to wait for this issue to be resolved